# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (2.0.0 peview1-final) migration is not creating tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new with Entity Framework and having issue with creating tables in DB.

The database is created fine but it doesn't create tables from entities.

Here is my Context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public MyContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

And here is `User` entity

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UsernaName {get; set;}
}
```

And this is the code which I have in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();

        }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddIdentityServiceAuthentication();

   services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlLiteConnection")));

   services.AddMvc();
 }
```

Migrate create database `context.Database.Migrate();` This is clear to me from the documentation, but I just cannot how to get tables created from entities.

Thanks for any help.

And not sure if it's important, my class `MyContext` is defined in Class Libarry project, not in web project

**EDIT:**

From @borisdj answer I figured out that I have to run this command from Package manager:

Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -Context MyContext -Project MyProject.Db

But I am getting this error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

As you can see I am not overriding `DbContext.OnConfiguring` but I am using `AddDbContext` in `Startup.cs` as you can see above and have constructor which accepts `DbContextOptions<TContext>` object but I am still getting this error.

Is it maybe because `MyContext` is defined in Class Library project and not in Web project (where Startup.cs is)

Answer (score 1):

You should first in Package Manager Console run this command:
*PM> add-migration Initial*

and then:
*PM> update-database*

If there are multiple DbContext-s in the App then DbContext Name needs to be specified:
*PM> dd-migration Initial -Context MyContext -Project MyProject.Db*

Regarding other issue with provider, you should have the following elements in your App:
**appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=CoreTemplate;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**MyContext.cs**

```
public partial class My Context : DbContext
{
    public CoreTemplateContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
```

Comment: when I run create-migration Initial getting error: The term 'create-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.....  I am runing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.0 (it's preview) and VS 2017

Comment: My bad, it's 'add-migration'

Comment: Great add-migration Initial helped. Just I got error that I have more then one DbContext so I had to specify DbContex like Add-Migration Initial -Context MyContext. Update your answer with this additional explanation in case you have more then one DbContext and I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Since your context is in class library, you need to specify startup project too